# struts form and JSTL

Tags: struts, jstl, el

How to access a form variable using JSTL ?

e.g.

```
<html:text property="abc" ... />

<c:out value="${abc}"/>
```

`abc` is always blank, even though I have value set by action sending to this page.

Comment: can you show how you're doing this: "value set by action sending to this page"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer with ActionForm, you can retrieve the value. "abc" is one of the property of ActionForm(you created) which will be available in request scope as it has been set in ActionServlet during processing request.

So get the value like this, suppose your ActionForm is 'TestForm', then retrieve as `${TestForm.abc}` or `<c:out value="${TestForm.abc}"/>`